# Access is Denied when typing psql in cmd windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd

I wanna access my postgre database using cmd in windows. I'm running my cmd as administrator, but when I type `psql` it will always be denied:
[image]

I have set my PostgreSQL directory permission as shown below:

[image]
[image]

I have also set the postgresql bin folder to full-control but still access denied. If I run this using powershell, then it will display this error:

[image]

I appreciate any answer thank you

Note:
[image]

Comment: Why do you have ¥ instead of \?

Comment: @stickybit my laptop locale is Japanese so it's shown like that. But it's still working even with that yen simbol as \

Comment: The message you're seeing doesn't say anything about not having access or permissions or sufficient privileges. What makes you think that those are the problem? If they were, the message would mention one of those issues.

Comment: @KenWhite bcs I saw other problem which almost same. And the solution is permission, so I set the permission also

Comment: The Powershell message you added tells you specifically that it is not that problem. It also tells you that the executable is not a valid executable for the OS. Did you actually read the words in the mssage? They're there for a reason, which is to provide you with useful information about the problem, but they can only do so if you actually read those words. **not a valid executable for the OS** does not mean *does not have privileges*.

Comment: so what's the solution? because if I use pgAdmin, it can run smoothly

Comment: What files do you have with that name. A 0 byte file, either bat or exe, will generate this message. Type `where psql /t`.

Comment: pgAdmin is apparently a valid Windows app. The solution is to do exactly what the first mesage told you, which is to go to the software vendor site to get the proper app for your Windows version, or a replacement copy that isn't corrupt somehow..

Comment: @Mark, I put the screenshot for `where psql /t`

Comment: Can psql run in a cmd/powershell window even? Do you have a Bash environment installed in your windows like cygwin?

Comment: Delete the 0 byte one. It may have been an attempt to have a batch file start psql but it didn't work.

Comment: Windows searches the current directory first. So it finds the 0 byte file first.

Comment: @aharith. I don't have cygwin, but I will install it then and see what's the result

Comment: @Mark. I take a look at bin folder closely and I didn't see any 0 byte file

Comment: @Mark. Oowwh yea I found it on system32 folder. it's 0 byte. Should I just delete this ?

Comment: Look at the output of the `where` command. It's in system32.

Comment: yes +1234567890 extra characters.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mark. Finally work ahaha... coool...

Answer (score 1):

So I followed the step from @Mark (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12431753/mark). So first thin to do is execute this command :

```
where psql /t
```

From that command I got something like this:

[image]

So there are 2 files of psql.exe. The first one is on System32 and the other one is in postgresql bin folder.

The next thing to do is delete the psql.exe which has 0 byte size. This file actually located on System32 (Sorry I forgot to screen shot it). After delete psql.exe in System32, then run psql command again in cmd and it's working now like this:

[image]

Thanks to Mark

Comment: Australians like me have their uses, neighbour. On blogspot there an app to translate your writings that - it puts a link on the side - it doesn't actually work on mine but it supposed to. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/

Comment: And as to why your path separator is so different see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051014-20/?p=33753 (I remember 15 year old posts).

Comment: @Mark I have no idea after reading https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/ and for my path separator, after reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051014-20/?p=33753, it's only like a comment. But it's okay for my yen simbols because everything still working. once I finished my japanese project, then I will turn my locale back to en ahah..

Comment: I meant to explain why, not that there was a problem. It interesting history.

Comment: oowh. Okay I thouht it was something that can fix my writing or my path separator ehe. Thanks btw @Mark :D